# How to safely unwrap a value from user defaults?

Tags: swift, option-type, userdefaults

```
if let seen: Bool = defaults.bool(forKey: UtilitiesKeys.mainTutorialSeen) {
    return seen
}
return false
```

if i do this swift shows me an issue:

> Conditional cast from 'Bool' to 'Bool' always succeeds, Non-optional
>   expression of type 'Bool' used in a check for optionals.

Since there might not be a value for my key, I don't want to force unwrap it. Now obviously it's working like this, but how do I safely unwrap the value without having swift complaining?

I have tried to use guard as well...

Comment: Hmm, displays the same issue but d0ye's answer works. Still thanks though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in doc:

> `-boolForKey:` is equivalent to `-objectForKey:`, except that it converts the returned value to a `BOOL`. If the value is an `NSNumber`, `NO` will be returned if the value is `0`, `YES` otherwise. If the value is an `NSString`, values of `"YES"` or `"1"` will return `YES`, and values of `"NO"`, `"0"`, or any other string will return `NO`. If the value is absent or can't be converted to a `BOOL`, `NO` will be returned.

```
open func bool(forKey defaultName: String) -> Bool
```

It is not an optional anymore. So you don't need to cast it with `if let`.

You can directly use:

```
let seen = defaults.bool(forKey: UtilitiesKeys.mainTutorialSeen)
```

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks, might as well do that since its the shortest way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if let seen = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UtilitiesKeys.mainTutorialSeen)) as? Bool {
        return seen
    }else {
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some context or an explanation of how this code solves the problem. This will make it more useful for more readers.

Comment: can u provide guard let?

Answer (score 1):

Apple document says:

> /*!
>        -boolForKey: is equivalent to -objectForKey:, except that it converts the returned value to a BOOL. If the value is an NSNumber, NO
>   will be returned if the value is 0, YES otherwise. If the value is an
>   NSString, values of "YES" or "1" will return YES, and values of "NO",
>   "0", or any other string will return NO. If the value is absent or
>   can't be converted to a BOOL, NO will be returned.

```
open func bool(forKey defaultName: String) -> Bool
```

**Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'**

hope this help you.